# Looking for a shortcut of list-initialization with consecutive integers

Tags: c++, initializer-list, iota

I have a bunch of longish hand initialized arrays, e.g.:

```
const std::array<int, 16> a{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
const std::array<int, 16> b{16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31};
...
```

Is there a way for a more concise initialization, e.g. along these lines (illegal):

```
const std::array<int, 16> a{std::views::iota(0, 16)};
const std::array<int, 16> b{std::views::iota(16, 32)};
...
```

Comment: This is not `std::initializer_list`, this is just aggregate initialization.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Edited the title, but not completely sure it was wrong, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/initializer_list. "Instances of std::initializer_list are implicitly constructed when: a braced-init-list is used in list-initialization"

Comment: Cppreference is wrong then, or they meant to say that it only happens in some of those cases. You could test this e.g. by doing `std::array<int, 3> x(std::initializer_list<int>{1,2,3});` (which doesn't compile), compared to the same thing with `std::vector`, which would compile. Also consider that aggregate init in general lets you initialize members of different types, while `initializer_list` only supports elements of the same type.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using plain old iota. Like so,

```
#include <array>
#include <numeric>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto make_range_array(T const & start) noexcept {
    std::array<T, N> range;
    std::iota(range.begin(), range.end(), start);
    return range;
}

auto main() -> int
{
    auto const a = make_range_array<int, 16>(0);
    auto const b = make_range_array<int, 16>(16);

}
```

Comment: In C++, `size_t` lives in the `std` namespace.

Comment: We should not assume that everyone has the same magic script that automatically changes `size_t` into `std::size_t`. Usually, answers on Stack Overflow are supposed to serve the wider community than just your co-workers. I think @Evg has a valid point because if there are even small errors in answers, those should still be fixed (either by you or by someone else) to not to mislead inexperienced readers who could potentially get an erroneous impression that the error is on their side.

Comment: @heapunderrun I think so too.  SO posts should be self-contained.  I have still upvoted this though ... and taken the liberty of adding it.

Comment: @Evg this is how it is done. I am sorry for my outburst. But, u have enough reputation to suggest edits. I spent quite some time compiling the code in my answer using clang, gcc and msvc on x86-64, arm, MIPS and rics-v to see if the assembly was equivalent. And then you come in and make a comment that is technically correct but is practically useless and it took you no more than 5 seconds to almost invalidate my efforts. A simple, add `std::` to `size_t`, to make your answer portable would have sufficed. I would made the edit. I am new here and your are a veteran, you should know better

Comment: I prefer to fix only trivial typos and write comments in other cases. My comment was written with good intentions, it was not meant to blame you or something like that. I make a comment, you make an edit, I upvote and we go on. That's how it works, almost always...

Comment: @evg. Thank for the clarification. I misunderstood your intentions. I am sorry. I will take this as a lesson and be more rigorous and charitable henceforth. It is only going to make me better. Thanks for your patience. I appreciate it

Answer (score 5):

With `std::index_sequence`, you might do something like:

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<int, N> make_iota_array(int start = 0)
{
    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        return std::array<int, N>{static_cast<int>(start + N)...};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Comment: Oooh, template lambda.  You win my vote because the code is beautiful.  It would please Einstein, too (for the same reason).  Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year.

Comment: This is limited by the total number of template parameter available. For some implementations this is as small as 256 (the lowest bound required by the standard).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way for a more concise initialization

Yes there is. You can write a helper `make_array` as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>

template<std::size_t start, std::size_t end>
std::enable_if_t<(end > start), std::array<int, end - start>> constexpr make_array()
{
    std::array<int, end - start> tempArray{};
    std::size_t count = 0;
    for(int &elem:tempArray)
    {
        elem = start + count;
        count++;
    }
    return tempArray;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto arr = make_array<16, 32>();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/enGYWG756)