# Initialize array with values and size depending on a parameter within the member initializer list of the constructor? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, member-initialization

I want to initialize an object `b`, which requires an array `a` as argument for its constructor. The size and values of `a` should depend on parameters `int d` and `int v`, namely,
`a = {0, v, 2*v, ..., d*(d-1)*v}`.

**Restrictions:** `B` does not allow move or copy assignment and does not provide functions for updates.

I would like to do something like this:

```
class C {
    Array<int> a; 
    B b; 
};

C::C(int d, int v): 
    a({0, v, 2*v, ..., d*(d-1)*v}), 
    b(a){}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I downvoted because this does not show any research effort as the dowvnote button recommends. You'll find many related SO posts for this. [Looking for a shortcut of list-initialization with consecutive integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77701458/looking-for-a-shortcut-of-list-initialization-with-consecutive-integers/)

Comment: Note the argument must be compile time constant. Make them template parameters instead.

Comment: Is `Array` supposed to be `std::array` or `std::vector`? Do you have to initialise it with values or can you just run a loop in constructor body?

Comment: Also [Initialize std array with numbers from 1-to N template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74364842/12002570) should solve the problem. It is trivial to change it to your needs.

Comment: @user12002570 Thank you for linking the other question and the fast comment. Naturally, this answer provides a possible solution: to "outsource" the creation of the array.

Comment: I was wondering whether creating such a brace-enclosed initializer list is possible.

Comment: Either way, thank you for helping me to resolve my issue.

Comment: @JBL There are ways to get around most(if not all) of the problems we encounter in C++ like creating such brace-enclosed initializer list. Glad it helped. You're welcome.